# nested negated css media queries not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I have four media queries which seem to be fine on edge and chrome but the two negated queries don't apply on mobile Safari so far.

Am I writing the negation wrong? Or is there a way to rephrase these queries?

```
.standalone-large, .standalone-small, .browser-large, .browser-small {
    display:none;
}


/* SMALL BROWSER */
@media (max-width: 799px) and (not (display-mode: standalone)){
    .browser-small {
        display: inline;
    }
}
/* SMALL STANDALONE */
@media (max-width: 799px) and (display-mode: standalone){
    .standalone-small {
        display: inline;
    }
}
/* LARGE BROWSER */
@media (min-width: 800px) and (not (display-mode: standalone)){
    .browser-large{
        display: inline;
    }
}
/* LARGE STANDALONE */
@media (min-width: 800px) and (display-mode: standalone){
    .standalone-large{
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Only one of the following elements is supposed to show up at a time, which works in chrome and edge but not in mobile safari:

```
<span class="standalone-small">standalone-small</span>
<span class="standalone-large">standalone-large</span>
<span class="browser-small">browser-small</span>
<span class="browser-large">browser-large</span>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#logical_operators might help

Comment: In level 3 spec looks like `not` must apply to the whole media check. Can't seem to find a caniuse page for some reason also

Comment: that’s slightly annoying as I need to place the browser styles behind the standalone styles then and re-specify everything that does not apply :/ is there another way to rephrase my queries?

Comment: Have you got something like <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> in the head element?

Comment: Yes: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Comment: You might be able to store your display mode in custom properties and apply it that way